# Making sure a counter has finished counting to a number before starting another counter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code that is two counters, one counts to 30000 then then next counts from there up to a higher number at a different speed.

The problem I have is that the first counter never actually gets to 30000 before the second counter kicks off. I thought that was the whole point of the complete parameter but it's actually just running for 1 second then starting the next counter. But I need it to count up that quickly so I can't change the duration.

How can I make sure the second counter starts only when the first counter has hit 30000?

```js
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  },
  done: function() {
    checker();
  }
});

function checker() {
  base = parseInt($(".Single").text());
  per_day = 18;
  newtarget = (base + per_day);
  $(".Single").text(newtarget);

  $({ Counter: base }).animate({
    Counter: $('.Single').text()
  }, {
    duration: 20000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    },
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">30000</span>
```

Comment: `base`, `per_day`, and `newtarget` should be declared in `checker()`, unless they're declared elsewhere.

Comment: The animation cannot perfectly consume the 1000 milliseconds while also updating the DOM on each "tick" of the animation clock. When I try "swing" instead of "linear" easing, it gets closer to 30000, probably because the ticks are a little more spread out.

Comment: Probably the simplest way to do it reliably would be to force the `<span>` to 30000 when the second counter starts.

Comment: @Pointy or, more specifically, when the first counter *finishes* as `step:` doesn't include `done:`

Comment: @freedomn-m hey correct, good point!

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that `step:` does not include the "last step".

If you count 1..2..3, it looks like it's 2 steps (starting at 1), but in animation terms, it's actually 1 *step* (1->2) then finishes with `done:` (2->3).

Update the UI with counter in the `done:` callback and it works fine (though the 20000 counter may appear to start too soon, so you may want a `setTimeout` on `checker()`).

```
$('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
```

```js
$({ Counter: 0 }).animate({
  Counter: $('.Single').text()
}, {
  duration: 1000,
  easing: 'linear',
  step: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
  },
  done: function() {
    $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    checker();
  }
});

function checker() {
  base = parseInt($(".Single").text());
  per_day = 18;
  newtarget = (base + per_day);
  $(".Single").text(newtarget);

  $({ Counter: base }).animate({
    Counter: $('.Single').text()
  }, {
    duration: 20000,
    easing: 'linear',
    step: function() {
      $('.Single').text(Math.ceil(this.Counter));
    },
  });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="Single">30000</span>
```